# If my job is exactly the same across three employers, is it considered one job or three for tax credit purposes?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-credit

The state of Oklahoma has a tax credit for engineers working in aerospace, described in [form 564](https://www.ok.gov/tax/documents/564-19.pdf). The definitions on page 2 specifically state under "Qualified Employee":

> [the employee] was not employed in the aerospace sector in Oklahoma immediately
>   preceding employment or contracting with a qualified employer

I take this to mean you can only claim the credit for a job as long as your previous job was not also with a qualifying employer. **Is that correct?**

Now for my situation:

- 2017 - graduated college and began working for a federal government contractor (W2-employee for Company A) in the aerospace industry
- 2018 - contract was awarded to a new company (W2-employee for Company B)
- 2019 - transferred over as a federal employee, no longer a contractor (W2-employee for federal government)

So, I technically had three jobs over the three years. I claimed the credit in 2017, 2018, and was planning to claim it for 2019 as well. While at first glance it may seem like "different jobs, no credit can be claimed", I believe my situation may be different.

During the three years and "three employers" I had the same desk, same coworkers, and the same work responsibilities. **Literally the only difference between the three "jobs" was the organization signing the paychecks.** While on paper I have W2s from three employers, I had the same job across all three. All three are "Qualified Employers". Note that the first two employers were contracted by the federal government but I was a W2 employee (not a contractor myself).

**Can I still claim the tax credit?**